# Salesforce: How to add a Custom Object to Search results

Tags: salesforce

Seems like a simple question, but I can't see where this is set.

I created a custom object, Account Thing, which is related to Accounts with a Master-Detail relationship.

It has a text area field, Body.

It has a Search Results Layout, and if i search for something contained in Body, a result returns.

I created another analogous custom object, Contact Thing.  It also has a text area field, Body.

It does not have a Search Results Layout.  If i search for something contained in Body, nothing returns.  Looking at the list of objects being searched in the results page, Account Thing is listed, but not Contact Thing (or any other custom object i have created)

I'm thinking there must be a flag or search setting that i set for Account Thing, but I can't find it now.

I looked under App Setup > Customize > Search > Search Settings,
but there is no relevant config there.

Any help is appriciated!

Comment: I did some digging and found the solution to this issue.

Apparently only Custom Objects that have their own tab are included in search results.
I had somehow created a tab for Account Thing (but removed it from view), but not for
any of the other Custom Objects.  After I added a tab, Contact Things were returned in relevant searches.

One other side piece of info is that the body was a Rich Text type, not a standard Text Area.  So that explains why it is searchable.

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging and found the solution to this issue.

Apparently only Custom Objects that have their own tab are included in search results.
I had somehow created a tab for Account Thing (but removed it from view), but not for
any of the other Custom Objects.  After I added a tab, Contact Things were returned in relevant searches.

One other side piece of info is that the body was a Rich Text type, not a standard Text Area.  So that explains why it is searchable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Body on Account think uses a text area? I didn't think those would be searchable as you can't use them in the where clause of a SOQL query so would be surprised if the system did search them. Other than that, is the object marked as 'Deployed' or 'In Development'? If the latter, it probably wouldn't appear.

Because this is a non-code question you may well get closed down here, please follow (and vote on some questions) my [Salesforce Stack Exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce), I'm putting it forward so that these kind of questions (which are valid Salesforce development questions) have somewhere to live on Stack Exchange network!

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the Account Thing has a text area as the body, although I think that's an aside to the problem.  The schema of the Account Thing and the Contact Thing are identical, except the object relationships they have.  Good thought on whether or not they were deployed, but I already verified that they are both deployed.

Comment: Does contact thing have a MD relationship to the Contact? Maybe that's the differentiator?

Comment: Yes, it does.  But why would that mean it can't be searched for?

Comment: Straw clutching! Do you have Chatter enabled so that you have global search? (i.e. the search box at the top of the screen that does everything, not the search in the LHS menu)